# How are Markov Kernels Related to SDEs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

(Disclaimer: *I've been working with SDEs for some years now but have not worked with general Markov processes before... so I'm trying to reconcile some ideas with this post.*)

---

I recently read the definition of a *Markov kernel* $K$ on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ as being a map $K:\Omega,\times \mathcal{F}\rightarrow [0,1]$ satisfying:

- $\omega \mapsto K(\omega,A)$ is measurable, for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$,
- $K(\omega,\cdot)$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$.

Suppose that $(X_t)_{0\leq t\leq 1}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued solution to the SDE:
$$
X_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dW_t,
$$
for some Brownian motion $(W_t)_{0\leq t\leq 1}$ and some smooth Lipschitz functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$.  I know that $(X_t)_{0\leq t\leq 1}$ has the Markov property, but how  does this to relate this to a *Markov kernel*?

In other words... what is the *Markov kernel* determining $(X_t)_{0\leq t\leq 1}$.

*(Excuse me if the question is silly, but I'm self-teaching Markov processes...)*

Comment: The SDE is specifying a family of Markov kernels $\lbrace p_{t} \rbrace_{t>0}$ via $\mathbb{E}^{X_{0}=x} f(X_{t})=\int f(y)p_{t}(x,dy)$.

Answer (score 0):

see answer here for more references [Each diffusion SDE is associated to a *unique* family of transition kernels](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451967/each-diffusion-sde-is-associated-to-a-unique-family-of-transition-kernels/451970#451970)

there are unique corresponding forward/backward equations (Fokker Plank) to an SDE, and unique solutions for them that correspond to transition kernels. See the nice notes here [Lecture 10: Forward and Backward equations for SDEs](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eholmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture10_2019.pdf) where they give more references also.

Since interested on the regularity issues, check out the beautiful work by A.Figalli
["Existence and uniqueness of martingale solutions for SDEs with rough or degenerate coefficients."](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123607X05986/1-s2.0-S0022123607003709/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEF0aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCrulAO2lbNLXiSfIwYKIjAtZLi%2F7OEMoORw%2BEkLJfObQIhAJMku7RO309TiGkrsAIsOTvXKPvGbFcvBp7O9rk%2BNXNPKrwFCPX%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgzaUpny%2B%2BfMw98H%2FlkqkAUp3rkjAx1u58%2FGgeH%2FadEJAvk1IZMn4gY6ZP3Y84HR5WdKQis0DvkzLoBlnVNg3%2B139UypnNGed8Fw1TA2SKA5qQ0wTWz129rp59HhdP7SlNTbJjqcJYBUm3N7ZxsP%2Be54NU5TLbLFs49I096GvsZVqzwFtfJbZrIWmDJfHK%2FUJaJCUO1F5dlN9A0fGNeTI6kFGE3OyC3Bik6n9MjqlC0D3ls%2BiUM6cfvOMqWBOqigfPAF4XiF41eq0LsjbJqcDna3olj9lsDEgD1GyLrzOdFV0JdKgwR6u8WpkCAjeIiG2HCrLiHx43Kt9R1pyiEpoDXtolCPwBL0Dcww8HkG0eAZSLs0UMO2KUMbHkue1yLEioGeAQRkO2iDqrrxKqBUc9Lv5Thgh9jygAgGJRauE6EsCDQC7jdXjSY%2FTnKwjvSx8SIQWVqfPZ2aZG56Z3iCJjaVgnGBvQ4VXsf1DhSmW2KgxpbAFVn%2FRC3TvUJrAa%2F4s3uJVLAnFDMNTtBtOyaU7liSoXmJcs3AiHdTH0pD6oe2Q6Ez7173VBCFKvWtBgPxbL0dqbKAYCoq7f%2FFhquoD1Y%2BrsMROHAVEAAhoyNDn%2BHlCz3catHkptF8ImnCdEGWrAgAWq88lI4SK0AXqo%2BNfPqfXrumbJuL7zFEdB3CX%2BM9%2BPZQ5K67mnyDZM02tS9eCjFu%2Fo%2BZhMRRPTUXuPkH91EJXAiqTXIYff8cAJKSRRtTiTDB9aMfAReNR4y3LXZUL5I0J1CiQtf5HSLG7j0O6jvBmhKQKpPkxpddSxlIYzKFrOp2D71G29svbZTgseJEci17aK0%2BTMOGaoJHpu9pAHvUQNXlcu1VyAXI3kV3R%2Bex5dJ8ZHZ5DuUD3jFJc136szC08KqmBjqwATnifgnqwX%2F7g%2F%2Bht2R9q90atue5vxfu03LS7gU3BVE2x%2Fl7m1lfLIAYCWIt7CevdzuMVzYPik8keVt6CN6qvOg6UX%2BRsJao545I5n%2FC%2BMPi3fPN6jDw%2B7ws7smLFTFWSEQZKuSkDUXFbtk4tL2FsXc6IuH5Yi3%2BeM1s2sqgsj3riA2QavFYqRsBZ3YuyiZbHaTwOvxZRgCSIvg9IMrnIZ0NCjYk8Q5gC%2B7Io5MMQYea&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230802T203252Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYQQ4743WO%2F20230802%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1bbd78a275e50fca5f197bf727ffe31b7762c1be7c5a5804142bcdfcb66d88ec&hash=ba7ef1b2dd8968de8b43d4294cb02c5d482f2365df954d2e28b87fd3f0878dc9&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022123607003709&tid=spdf-e7ee82a0-0869-4eee-9dbd-a2160938023f&sid=845b034a3770a742851a33496d605894132dgxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=06065807515e57550600&rr=7f0917ba59e439ed&cc=ca)

Also, check out the third-chapter on PDEs from Stroock-Varadhan work "Multidimensional Diffusion Processes".